# Can't use FrameLayout in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I got this strange problem where I can't use FrameLayout in ViewPager. When it was RelativeLayout it wass all good and safe. Now when I wanted to change to FrameLayout - it crashes at start:

```
    12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357): Process: pl.dajsiezlapac.apka, PID: 19357
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at pl.dajsiezlapac.apka.ViewPagerAdapter.isViewFromObject(ViewPagerAdapter.java:52)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.infoForChild(ViewPager.java:1333)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-17 18:03:30.528: E/AndroidRuntime(19357):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is ViewPagerAdapter.java (lines 50,51 and 52 respectively - so the problem lies in 'return'):

```
  @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
```

Comment: why are you casting to `RelativeLayout` if you are using a `FrameLayout`?

Comment: You may have correctly cast after changing the layout, but I've notice in Eclipse that sometimes the resource IDs to not update unless you clean your project (and sometimes I'm even forced to restart Eclipse). I'd start there is your cast is valid for the new layout. The reference to the now discarded `RelativeLayout` may be incorrectly persisting.

Comment: I tried to cas to FrameLayout, but then I get "Incompatible operand types View and FrameLayout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayout` are different classes. You cannot cast a `FrameLayout` to be a `RelativeLayout`.

Get rid of the cast in `isViewFromObject()`. Or, at the very least, cast it to `View` or `FrameLayout` (which would be valid) rather than `RelativeLayout` (which is not valid).

Comment: If I get rid of this I get "The type ViewPagerAdapter must implement the inherited abstract method PagerAdapter.isViewFromObject(View, Object)" error, but casting View made it work! Thanks!